# Open emacs in new window when sudo-ing

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, ubuntu-16.04, emacs24

I'm trying to use emacs to edit some file under /usr. When I use

sudo emacs filename.txt

it automatically uses -nw mode. Is there anyway to open a new window when I use sudo emacs?

My emacs version is 24.5.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Tramp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/) to open files as sudo. First open up Emacs in a window, then run:

```
C-x C-f /sudo::/usr/yourfile
```